# Не запускается IntelliJ Idea Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Ни с того ни с сего перестала запускаться intelliJ Idea Ultimate 2019.2.
Выдает ошибку: [image: Скриншот ошибки]

Пошарил по файлам vmoptions, такой настройки не нашел.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321964/maxjavastacktracedepth-1-failed-to-create-jvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалить файл studio64.exe.vmoptions из C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config